# Why I have this error when I try to install this old blog on my local webserver?

Tags: localhost, local-installation, wp-load.php, wp-blog-header.php

I am pretty new to WP (I came from Joomla) and I am finding some difficulties trying to put on my local web server an old backup of a website (made using WP 3.5)

I have performed the following operation:

1) I have put the website backup into a directory named **blog** into my Apache **www** directory on my Ubuntu local system.

2) Then I have put the database backup on my MySql local server

3) Finally I have change the values in the **wp-config.php** file to use my local DB

The problem is that when I try to open the URL to see the website I see noting (a white screen)

Into the Apache log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log) I found the following errors messages:

```
[Fri Jan 10 22:04:50 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:38 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:38 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:39 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:39 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
```

Why? what could be the problem? How can I try to solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Please do not create multiple questions about same issue. You can edit questions to add additional details. I've closed first one as duplicate since this has more details, but really that one should have been edited with these details.

Comment: My first thought is that there is a permissions problem.